# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I use JAXB 2 to parse an XML file against an XSD schema and the XML tags are automatically unmarshalled during ant build to Java classes. Some `enums` are created. The code is:

```
@XmlType(name = "binQuality")
@XmlEnum
public enum BinQuality {

    GOOD,
    BAD,
    UGLY,
    NULL;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static BinQuality fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

In my code I call:

```
BinQuality bq = BinQuality.valueOf(him.getToBinQuality());
```

in a loop and I get the exception only in the 91st iteration.

*********** UPDATED *****************

`him.getToBinQuality()` does return a valid enum (GOOD/BAD/UGLY/NULL). Below is an excerpt of logs.

```
....
2011-07-18 15:28:09 DEBUG (com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl:183) -> class com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl|exportToXml|him.getToBin():89|him.getToBinQuality():BAD
2011-07-18 15:28:09 DEBUG (com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl:183) -> class com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl|exportToXml|him.getToBin():90|him.getToBinQuality():UGLY
2011-07-18 15:28:09 DEBUG (com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl:183) -> class com.st.mas.wmr.persistence.process.ProcessStifOliBinConversionCompleteImpl|exportToXml|him.getToBin():91|him.getToBinQuality():BAD 
2011-07-18 15:28:09 WARN  (org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor:538) -> Unhandled Exception thrown: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

This seems really mysterious.

Java version used is 1.5.

Appreciate it.

Will

Comment: And what is the value of `him` in the 91st iteration?

Comment: Found it. there's a trailing space in the 91st data. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because no enum value could be found for your 91th entry. What is the value of the failed String?

Comment: Found it. there's a trailing space in the 91st data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Either your XML does not have a valid ENUM value (like 'good' in lowercase) or it has an empty tag, because if you try to eval an enum element via `MyEnum.valueOf(null)` it will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: If the value is `null`, `valueof` will throw `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is because that `him.getToBinQuality()` does not return the valid string which is in this case String should be `'GOOD|BAD|UGLY|NULL'`

You can easily debug this by printing the value on the log.